# Can Not Deauthorize a Computer in Music

Tags: itunes, apple-id, music, music.app, authorization

I reached the limit of five authorized computers per account.

The error message points one to this help page.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/118292

Here is the twist. I don't have 5 computers, I deauthorized them all in the past.
So in my settings there is no option to manage and remove devices, as there is only one.

Which probably the current one.

[image: screenshot]

I also checked on in the Apple ID all the associated computers, and all the old ones were removed. There is now only one iPhone and one mac.

https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage/section/devices

I tried all possible options, also iOS and macOS settings display the devices., but I don't see any other option to authorize the current computer.

So the question basically is how to deauthorized the 4–5 computers that I can't see in the usual locations.

Comment: What is your question?  Did you try contacting Apple Support re: these phantom computers attached to your account?

Comment: There should be a button underneath "Change Country or Region" (translated to "Land oder Region ändern"). The button should say "Deauthorize All". But from your screenshot it seems to be missing. Could you try changing Apple Music's language to English and see if the button shows up? You can change the language in `System Preferences`>`Language & Region`>`Apps` and add Apple Music and change the language to English. This won't affect the language settings for all your other applications. Restart Apple Music (or your Mac entirely) once you've set the language to English for Apple Music.

Comment: AVelj, switched Music to english, the app is now in english but not the account setting. They are still in German: . Thanks, anyway, I didn't know such an option existed to force languages on app level. Quite neat!